# Nuxt/Vue super slow compile for dev server when loading dynamic images

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm building a site with Nuxt, and I'm trying to require images dynamically in the `template` section. However, whenever I do this, it will make my compile time for the dev server for every change go from half a second to 8 seconds, and then longer for every new dynamic image that I add (getting up to minutes).

```
<img :src="require(`~/assets${blog.image}?size=400`)" />
```

Is there a way to dynamically require an image and not make the dev build way slower?

Comment: whats `?size=400` some kind of resizer? perhaps resize your images first.

Comment: How many files are in `/assets`? You're creating a context for that entire directory which can really be cumbersome. Maybe move some of these images into a sub directory within assets.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm using nuxt-optimized-images, which uses responsive-loader to resize images. I will try resizing first, but when I put the path in without the use of a variable, it is very fast and I see no performance hit, so I think it may be that I'm requiring a dynamic path.

Comment: @Sphinx, I read the documentation, but I'm not clear on how that would help with performance?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy when I try expanding it to include more directories, it doesn't seem to interpolate and get the full url:

~/assets/cms-upload/${blog.image}?size=400

Gives me an error that this dependency was not found:

~/assets/cms-upload?size=400